# Canvas Issues when Unit Testing Phaser and TypeScript with Mocha on Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, html5-canvas, mocha.js, phaser-framework

I'm currently developing a TypeScript/Phaser (2.6.2) project and attempting to run unit tests, set up to use Mocha and Chai (with `ts-node/register` and `jsdom-global/register`) on a Node environment with `node-canvas` installed using the [installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) for Windows.

The project builds using webpack and runs in the browser correctly, as does Compodoc, and tests that do not require Phaser are also able to execute and pass. Example class/test:

**phaser.game.class.ts**:

```
import { Phaser } from 'phaser'

export class Game extends Phaser.Game {
    constructor() { super(1280, 720, Phaser.AUTO, 'game') }
}
```

**phaser.game.class.spec.ts**:

```
import 'mocha'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { Game } from './phaser.game.class'

describe('Game', () => {
    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(Game).to.exist
    })
})
```

However when running tests that do import Phaser I receive an error:

```
 context.drawImage(magenta, 0, 0);
            ^
 TypeError: Expected object, number and number
```

Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/487) I believe it may be related to Phaser using a different canvas build to that which is installed with `node-canvas`, but I cannot force the use of a certain `node-canvas` version (as is described there) as ultimately this will be run in a browser - **is this the case, and is there any method to ensure the canvas version just for the tests?**

Alternatively I've looked into using [phaser-mock](https://github.com/byondreal/phaser-mock) and [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) (which I would prefer for simply testing isolated class logic), but am experiencing other issues and am unable to find an example implementation combining the two.

Any information would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have a similar problem too. I'm using Jest to unit test my Phaser 3 Typescript classes. But I can't really use Phaser 3 inside the jest environment.

Comment: I ended up not importing or extending Phaser in much of my logic/classes and isolating the Phaser imports to a few root files to then still run tests on the majority of the codebase - not much of a solution but hope it helps, you may also want to look at  https://stackoverflow.com/q/59567372/2030247 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/55690117/2030247