# mocking Phaser with Jest

Tags: jestjs, phaser-framework, ts-jest

I've been trying to set up jest as a test framework for a project I'm working on that uses Phaser, and I am getting stuck trying to mock out Phaser itself. I first ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269093/how-to-add-canvas-support-to-my-tests-in-jest#answer-33278679) with the missing canvas, which I was able to resolve from the link. But now I am getting another error "Cannot read property 'postion' of undefined".

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ['./src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
  },
  setupFiles: ['jest-canvas-mock']
}
```

__mocks__/phaser.js:

```
const phaser = jest.genMockFromModule('phaser');

module.exports = phaser;
```

error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

      1 | 
    > 2 | const phaser = jest.genMockFromModule('phaser');
        |                     ^
      3 | 
      4 | module.exports = phaser;

      at Image.get [as x] (node_modules/phaser/src/physics/matter-js/components/Transform.js:36:30)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__mocks__/phaser.js:2:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/main.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/main.spec.ts:3:1)
```

I'm looking at that Transform file and its blowing up on a getter because this.body is undefined:

```
get: function ()
{
  return this.body.position.x;
},
```

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm hoping I just have some configuration wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank you for sharing your configuration to run Jest with Phaser 3.

Regarding your issue, it appears that the `Phaser.Physics.Matter.Commponents.Trasnform` component is not really compatible with the way `jest.genMockFromModule()` works.

You can hack it simply by creating a default value for the `body` property of the `Transform` instance in `phaser/src/physics/matter-js/components/Trasnform.js`:

```js
var Transform = {

    body: Body.create({}),

    // ...
```

Although I don't know how it might affect the production code.

If you don't use the Matter.js physics engine in your game, maybe you could create a [custom Phaser 3 build](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-custom-build) instead.